# Add a percentage sign in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

How can I add a percentage sign '%' in cbrange, like this map I saw. Or adding the percentage sign behind the number? I try the code `{/Symbol \045}`, but it didn't work.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was hoping that there is a title for the colorbox as there is for the key to put some text on top, but I couldn't find.
Then, I see at least 3 options:

1. `cblabel`. Check `help xlabel`
2. `format cb`. Check `help format`
3. `label`. Check `help label`. Independent of color box. Might be tedious to find the right coordinates.

**Code:**

```
### units for the colorbox
reset session

set multiplot layout 1,3

    set cblabel "%" rotate by 0
    plot x w l palette

    unset cblabel
    set format cb "%g%%"
    replot

    unset format cb
    set label 1 "%" at graph 1.02,1.03
    replot
    
unset multiplot
### reset session
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!!